# Validate name and address with the card number

Tags: paypal

I'm using Paypal Pro API to process my purchase. It works well with card number, expire date and security code but I need to validate the address and the owner name of the card as well.

Is there any parameters or functions in the API to do this? I didn't found anything in the docs. Or maybe it is an additional option in the Paypal developer control panel?

Comment: The answer below covers [AVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Verification_System). That's pretty much it in the context of _credit card_ payments (or use an additional anti-fraud service). If its not enough, a `paypal` payment (e.g. Express Checkout), where you can leverage [Paypal Seller Protection](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/security/seller-protection) might be something you can look into. Hth.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that we're talking about the Payflow Gateway API (for PayPal Payments Pro and other things), it appears you can do address verification--see the section entitled [Using Address Verification Service](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#using-address-verification-service). Notice the note there that says it doesn't check street names, in case that's a deal-breaker for you.

As for name validation, I can't find anything about that other than that it's typically passed in the sale transaction itself (section: [Typical Sale Transaction Parameter String](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#typical-sale-transaction-parameter-string)). Whether it's then validated by the banks as part of their end of the transaction, I couldn't say.

Hope that gets you a bit further. I haven't worked with any of this stuff myself.